# What is the best technique for real time server-client communication?

Tags: python, flask

I need to create a web site with Flask or Django where I can plot real time sensor (IOT) reading without loosing any information. is sockets the best solution ? or there exists another solution which serve better for this task ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use DJANGO or FLASK to present information from your source sensors, I would suggest you using WEBSOCKETs.

In DJANGO, you have [DJANGO CHANNELS](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).